# Python: NameError for no apparent reason?

Tags: python, nameerror

```
 from random import random

 def computer():
 computer = 0
 while computer < 21:
  val = int(random()*10)+1
  if (computer + val) > 21:
   break
  else:
   computer += val
 print "Ich habe ", computer, "!"
 return computer


    def player():
 player = 0
 loss = 0
 while player < 21:
                hval = int(random()*10)+1
                print "Du hast ", hval, "...\nNoch eine mit y..."
                if raw_input == "y":
                        player += hval
                        if player > 21:
                                print "Du hast verloren!"
                                loss = 1
                                break
                        else:
                                continue
                else:
                        player += hval
                        break
        return player
        return loss

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        player()
        if loss == 1: #This is where I get the NameError.
                pass
        else:
                computer()
                if computer > player:
                        print "Ich habe gewonnen!"
                else:
                        print "Du hast gewonnen"
```

I returned loss in player() so I don't know why I keep getting this NameError.

Comment: Your indentation is horrible; I've edited to make it show as code but this just makes the problem more obvious...

Answer (score 3):

Let's clean that mess up and see what all the errors are:

```
from random import random # tip, check out randint (the function in the random module)

def computer():
    computer = 0
    while computer < 21:
        val = int(random()*10)+1 # please use some whitespace around operators

        if (computer + val) > 21:
            break

        else:
            computer += val

    print "Ich habe ", computer, "!"
    return computer

def player():
    player = 0
    loss = 0

    while player < 21:
        hval = int(random()*10)+1 # again, whitespace improves readability
        print "Du hast ", hval, "...\nNoch eine mit y..."

        if raw_input == "y": # raw_input is a function (hint you need to call the function)
                             # you're comparing the object against a string
                             # that will always yield false, therefore the player
                             # never gets the chance to enter another number

            # this never gets executed
            player += hval
            if player > 21:
                print "Du hast verloren!"
                loss = 1
                break

            else:
                continue

        # always gets executed
        else:
            player += hval
            break

    return player # this returns the value of player
    return loss # never reached, dead code, the return above has already left the function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    player() # returns the integer, but doesn't assign it to any name

    if loss == 1: # loss is not defined in this scope
        pass

    else:
        computer() # again, this doesn't assign the returned value

    if computer > player: # if this would get reached, it would fail yet again
                          # no name error this time, but you're comparing the function object
                          # against the player object, this will (at least in CPython)
                          # compare the memory addresses

        print "Ich habe gewonnen!"

    else:
        print "Du hast gewonnen"
```

Now you know all the errors, it's up to you to fix them :)

But I also want to note that your indentation is a **REAL** mess, **ranging from 1 space to 16** per indent.
Especially in Python were indentation is an essential part of the syntax, this is by no means tolerable.

Please read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on how to style your code.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `return loss` it returns the *value* of loss, not the variable. Therefore the name `loss` doesn't exist in the calling scope.

You need to assign the result to a local variable (which also can be called loss) like this:

```
loss = player()
```

Comment: additionally, you can't return 2 values from a function; the function stops executing when the first `return` statement is reached.

Comment: @Wooble: True... didn't notice that until you reformatted the code. There are also a lot of other errors as well, such as the comparison `computer > player` on two functions and the incorrect call to `raw_input`, to give a couple of examples.

Answer (score 0):

loss is not defined in your script, post your entire script so we can follow it through, it could be you are trying to refer to a variable you used inside player()

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your formatting, but apart from that, if you returned `loss` from `player()`, you didn't save it anywhere.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loss = player()   # the loss returned by player is now within the local loss
    if loss == 1: #This is where I get the NameError.
            pass
```